# Unexpected strings "botbuilder-location:TitleSuffix" and "botbuilder-location:MultipleResultsFound" when using BotBuilder-Location

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have tried using BotBuilder-Location to collect the user's location via the Bing Maps API. I have followed the instructions on BotBuilder-Location's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) and have managed to be able to display a map fron Bing Maps using the code from the example:

```
var options = {
prompt: "Where should I ship your order?",
    useNativeControl: true,
    reverseGeocode: true,
    requiredFields:
    locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.streetAddress |
    locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.locality |
    locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.region |
    locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.postalCode |
    locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.country
};
locationDialog.getLocation(session, options)
```

However, in the prompt for the location the string "botbuilder-location:TitleSuffix" keeps showing, and the dialog does not continue after showing the map but instead displays the string "botbuilder-location:MultipleResultsFound" ([Screenshot of unexpected strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCnk8.png)). I have tried this in the Emulator as well as on Skype and Facebook Messenger with the same results.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known issue and it's reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/issues/44). There you will also find a workaround. The team behind the control is testing a potential fix.